# Assigning Directory as a Variable in R

Tags: r

I need to create a function called `PollutantMean` with the following arguments: `directory`, `pollutant`, and `id=1:332`)

I have most of the code written but I can't figure out how to assign my directory as a variable.  My current working directory is `C:/Users/User/Documents`.  I tried writing the variable as:

`directory <- "C:/Users/User/specdata"` and that didn't work.

Next I tried the following:

`directory <- list.files("specdata", full.names=TRUE)` and that didn't work either.

Any ideas on how to change this?

Comment: What didn;t work? `directory<="C:/Users/...etc"` "works" in that it assigns the name of that directory to the variable. How exactly did your `list.files` thing not work? Error message? Computer exploded? We can only guess. Are you trying to change your current working directory? You want `setwd` then.

Comment: if you read your question carefully you see that the command should be `list.files("../specdata", ...`

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to assign the values in your current working directory to the variable "directory" Why not take the simple method and add:

`directory <- getwd()`

This should take the contents of the working directory and assign the values to the variable "directory".

Answer (score 1):

I've already worker with directory as variables, I usually declare them like that

```
directory<-"C://Users//User//specdata//"
```

To take back your example.
Then, if I want to read a specific file in this directory, I will just go like :

```
read.table(paste(directory,"myfile.txt",sep=""),...)
```

It's the same process to write in a file

```
write.table(res,file=paste(directory,"myfile.txt",sep=""),...)
```

Is this helping ?

EDIT : you can then use read.csv and it will work fine

Comment: I apologize for now being more specific.  I have a folder called specdata that contains 332 different csv files (numbered 001.csv - 332.csv) with many rows of data for pollutants.  I need to merge all these files together and take a grand mean of all the pollutants.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused by the assignment operation in `R`. The following line

```
directory <- "C:/Users/User/specdata"
```

assigns a string to a new object that just happened to be called `directory`. It has the same effect on your working environment as

```
elephant <- "C:/Users/User/specdata"
```

To change where `R` reads its files, use the function `setwd` (short for set working directory):

```
setwd("C:/Users/User/specdata")
```

You can also specify full path names to functions that read in data (like `read.table`). For your specific problem,

```
# creates a list of all files ending with `csv` (i.e. all csv files)
all.specdata.files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/User/specdata", pattern = "csv$")

# creates a list resulting from the application of `read.csv` to 
# each of these files (which may be slow!!)
all.specdata.list <- lapply(all.specdata.files, read.csv)
```

Then we use `dplyr::rbind_all` to row-bind them into one file.

```
library(dplyr)
all.specdata <- rbind_all(all.specdata.list)
```

Then use `colMeans` to determine the grand means. Not sure how to do this without seeing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the columns in each of the 300+ csv files are the same, that is have column j contains the same type of data in all files, then the following example should be of use:

```
# let's use a temp directory for storing the files
tmpdr <- tempdir()

# Let's creat a large matrix of values and then split it into many different
# files
original_data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10000L), nrow = 1000L))

# write each row to a file
for(i in seq(1, nrow(original_data), by = 1)) { 
  write.csv(original_data[i, ], 
            file = paste0(tmpdr, "/", formatC(i, format = "d", width = 4, flag = 0), ".csv"), 
            row.names = FALSE)
}

# get a character vector with the full path of each of the files
files <- list.files(path = tmpdr, pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)

# read each file into a list
read_data <- lapply(files, read.csv)

# bind the read_data into one data.frame, 
read_data <- do.call(rbind, read_data)

# check that our two data.frames are the same.  
all.equal(read_data, original_data)
# [1] TRUE
```